# How can I cast integer PK s from legacy MySQL database int MongoDB's ObjectID?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, objectid

I want to migrate from MySQL to MongoDB.

In MySQL, PKs are integer. I want to cast them into ObjectID

When I try:

```
mongo.ObjectID(theInteger)
```

altough theInteger is same, results are different.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a new id from theInteger or use theInteger as the Id?

Comment: I am trying to generate a new id from integer.

Answer (score 1):

`ObjectId` is a hexadecimal, 24-byte chars type from MongoDB. In other words, you can't cast from a int.

The best you could do to maintain your MySQL data structure is use your MySQL PK in `_id` field, you'll have no trouble with this.

Comment: Yes, but I will have troubles about it. For example, _id cannot auto_increment when insert. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you're right. See here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId is a special type of mongodb, but if you just want to migrate, you can store integer id of mysql to mongodb's '_id'.